# how to get the return value of wpa_supplicant?

Tags: linux, shell-script, networking, networkmanager

My question is really simple

I want to get the return value of the command `wpa_supplicant`, when connected to the internet, to know that I am connected or not with a shell script.

Comment: usually you can read the exit code of the last command with `echo $?`

Comment: the problem is that wpa_supplicant is a daemon

Answer (score 3):

In Linux, you can get the return value of any commands by getting value of special variable `$?` immediately after running that command:

```
command
return_code=$?
echo $return_code
```

But in your case, I recommend you to use `wpa_cli` to notify you are connected or not. First, create a script, named `notify.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$2" in
    CONNECTED)
        notify-send "WPA supplicant: CONNECTED";
        ;;
    DISCONNECTED)
        notify-send "WPA supplicant: DISCONNECTED";
        ;;
esac
```

Make script execuable, then:

```
wpa_cli -a notify.sh
```

Comment: Your response sounds reasonable but I have problem with wpa_cli that doesn't connect to wpa_supplicant

Comment: You must run `wpa_supplicant` first, then using `wpa_cli` to get it status.

Comment: The solution is to add /var/run/wpa_supplicant in a file !
But i'm trying to figure out why I don't have this file

Comment: You can see this link for more details: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant

Comment: Actually I was there

Answer (score 0):

test `$?`, if it is 0 everything went OK, if it is not then the previous command did not end successfully.

So something like

```
wpa_suplicant.......
if (( ! $? ))
then
    #everything went OK
else
    #wpa failed.
fi
```

should work.

The check of `$?` MUST be right after the command (wpa_suplicant in your case), otherwise you will be cheking other command's result.

Comment: sorry this doesn't work because wpa_supplicant is a kind of a daemon

Comment: wpa_supplicant when it is executed can fail fail and then work

Comment: Then redirect the output to a file (-f) and check that file to see if the connection was succesfull.

Comment: -_- No Comment !